# Confusion in object

Tags: javascript

Note : Both statements are inside the objects in which name property  is present

Statement 1:

```
sayHello : function()
  {
   return `Hello, my name is ${this.name}`;
  }
```

Statement 2

```
sayHello (){
    return `Hello, my name is ${this.name}`;
  }
```

// both are giving desired output i.e. there is no any syntax error but is there any difference between the above Statements

Comment: [Shorthand method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference at all, `statement2` way of writing method introduced in ES6.